# How to check if in a folder exists some file in PHP

Tags: php, file

I'm confusing :S with this script...This script working if there are some file, and I will get the echo like:

```
|test1.txt|test2.txt|test3.txt|test4.txt
```

the problem is when doesn't exist any file, the php will get an error:

```
Warning: asort() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in htdocs\test\ReadFolder8.php on line 6

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in htdocs\test\ReadFolder8.php on line 8
```

is possible to make a function who look if there are the file, if not, get an echo like "no file found" without error?

```
<?php
    $User = $_GET['User'];

    foreach (glob("Myuser/$User/*.txt") as $path) { 
        $docs[$path] = filectime($path);
    } asort($docs); // sort by value, preserving keys

    foreach ($docs as $path => $timestamp) {
        //print date("d M. Y:|H:i:s |", $timestamp);
        print '|'. basename($path) .'' . "" . '';

    }
?>
```

the last thing, I don't understand how works the order for the data creation of file... if I create a new file, the new file will the last of the string...how I can invert the order??

Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is simple: You need to initialize your variable $docs before you use it to an empty variable like this:

```
$docs = array(); // <-- create array $docs before use...

foreach (glob("Myuser/$User/*.txt") as $path) { 
    $docs[$path] = filectime($path);
}
asort($docs); // sort by value, preserving keys
```

To let the function output an error message instead, if there are no such files, you can simply count the number of array elements using `count($docs)` and check if it is 0 like this:

```
if (count($docs) == 0) {
    echo "no file found";
}
```

Comment: Added some code/explanation for the error-case handling.

Comment: You can of course also use `if (!file_exists(glob("Myuser/$User/"))) { .... error ... }` to check if the directory exists. Note that file_exists() also works for directories.

Comment: Thanks!! it's working perfect!! the last question is...How order the file by date? the newest file it's the last... thanks again!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use arsort() instead of asort() to get the latest file as first.